# jQuery script doesnt trigger

Tags: jquery

I have these two piece of scripts on my custom.js file. The first one triggers fine. But the second doesnt. Am I doing something wrong, like missing a bracket or something? I tried JSLing, but couldnt figure it out. Thanks guys

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".SubmitWrapper").click(function() {
        $(".SubmitWrapper").replaceWith('<div class="SubmitWrapper"><div class="Button_Submit2"><a onClick="" href=""><span>Please ..</span></a></div></div>');
        alert('fdsfds');
    });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', 'ul.NFSelectOptions li', 'a', function() {
        if ($(this).text() == "Feedback") {
            $('body').html("hihi");
            alert("Goodbye!");
        }
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
$(document).on('click', 'ul.NFSelectOptions li', 'a', function() {
```

It should be this:

```
 $(document).on('click', 'ul.NFSelectOptions li a', function() {
```

All the pieces of the selector go in one string, not in two arguments.  Your way puts the function in the wrong argument so it can never be called.

Comment: It didnt work. But 2nd script works fine by its own. see : http://jsfiddle.net/N5t6A/

Comment: @Uds - there's nothing in your jsFiddle that matches the selector.  There are no ul tags, no li tags, no a tags.   Please show us ALL the relevant HTML.  Perhaps your selector is wrong too.

Comment: @Uds In the fiddle, you are using your _wrong_ selector again!

Comment: @Uds - OK, I guess you have some sort of add-in that is modifying your forms and adding this HTML.  Anyway, this code seems to work fine for me here.  If I click General Enquiry and select Feedback, the alert triggers.

Comment: @jfriend00  - Im using niceForms jquery plugin to enhance the drop downs. If you firebug the results, you'll see the UL tags and LIs. Sorry, I forgot to mention. But it still deostn work.

Answer (score 0):

Combine them.  Edit: got it.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".SubmitWrapper").click(function () {
        $(".SubmitWrapper").replaceWith('<div class="SubmitWrapper"><div class="Button_Submit2"><a onClick="" href=""><span>Please ..</span></a></div></div>');
        alert('fdsfds');
    });
    $('form').on('click', 'ul li', 'a', function(){
        if($(this).text() == "Feedback"){
            $("#adminForm_1").html("hihi");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: still the second doesn't trigger.

Comment: This is a compactness suggestion, but doesn't have anything to do with the problem.

Comment: @Uds it was your selector.  use `$('form').on('click', 'ul li', 'a', function(){});`